# Ubuntu: Keep emacs in the terminal

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I installed emacs on Ubuntu 10.10 using `sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot-gtk`

I prefer my emacs in the terminal and everytime I emacs something, it pops up in some fancy GUI window. How do I go old-school?

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Start it with:

```
emacs -nw
```

If you're using `bash` you can set an alias by adding to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias emacs='emacs -nw'
```

Comment: Useful idea, but then you can't just $ emacs myfile - it will append -nw as bytes to the opened file.

Comment: I don't think so, with that alias `emacs myfile` is the same as `emacs -nw myfile` and that's perfectly legit since `-nw` gets parsed as an option.

Comment: "Perfectly legit" seems to be very individual, since I'm very used to the fact that when I open a file, the string '>1;3201;0c' won't be prepended to the file's head and the buffer won't be marked as modified. It may work for you, but not for me, sorry.

Comment: `emacs -nw` then C-x C-f works perfectly, but why `emacs -nw myfile` doesn't work, I don't know.

Comment: @LukaRamishvili My Emacs has never done anything of the sort when using `emacs -nw myfile`. Perhaps it was a bug fixed sometime between 2012 and 2017.

Comment: @RadonRosborough I'm using latest stable. macOS here, maybe that's the problem. Additionally, different system and emacs configurations may cause different behaviour.

Comment: @LukaRamishvili I'm also using Emacs 25.2 and macOS 10.11. My Emacs is installed from Homebrew Cask. Interesting to know that the bug still exists for some system configurations.

Answer (score 6):

What about installing the no X window system version:

```
apt-get install emacs-snapshot-nox
```

Comment: It is `emacs24-nox` for Ubuntu 14.04. Just for the reference.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 it's just `emacs-nox`

Answer (score 4):

There's another solution to "make emacs open files quickly" - just start emacs with

```
emacs -f server-start
```

and then open every file with

```
emacsclient -n <file>
```

If you have emacs client running - this command opens text file in a moment!

To make this solution more usable you can

1. make emacs server starting at start-up
2. put `alias ec='emacsclient -n'` in ~/.bashrc
3. If you use Krusader - you can set there `emacsclient -n` as a default notepad - so it opens a file with F4.

Comment: Just use `emacsclient -n -a <file>`. Then the server will be started and backgrounded automatically if necessary.